# android ApiDemos invalid resource directory name 'transitino'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm studying the android sample project, I imported the project ApiDemos to my Eclipse, there're many errors and warnings appeared, the first one is: invalid resource directory name transition. And I used the solution from other threads, which are edit project.properties file set target to android-19,  update to latest SDK Tools, lastest ADT plugin, check Java compiler 1.6, clear and rebuild project. All don't work..Anyone can solve my problem. Thanks very much...